# Xamarin Using List from previous page to populate List view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm navigating from one page to another (using Navigation.PushModalAsync). The first page has a list. The second page has a list view. I want to pass on that list to the second page and then populate a list view with data from that list. How do I go about this?

kind regards

UPDATE:
It appears as though my listview isn't appearing. I tried manually setting the itemsource and the next page is still blank. I have this method:

```
        protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var listView = new ListView();
        //listView.ItemsSource = dataSource;
        listView.ItemsSource = new string[]{
  "mono",
  "monodroid",
  "monotouch",
  "monorail",
  "monodevelop",
  "monotone",
  "monopoly",
  "monomodal",
  "mononucleosis"
};

        listView.RowHeight = 40;
    }
```

But the next page remains blank with just a red background. To add to this, I don't seem to have the listview.ItemSource.Add() method.

Comment: I'd advise you to take a look at C# Properties and at Jason's response !

Comment: When I first tried passing it as an argument, I had an error with my constructor. Thought it was just Xamarin being buggy but I knew it should've been possible/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Messaging Center in Xamarin Forms here, which is one option: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

Or another option is just passing the list in the constructor of the modal you are pushing. In my opinion, using the messaging center is a much cleaner way.

Comment: Can you give an example on how it would work in this case? Documentation usually lacks context.

Answer (score 2):

in Page1

```
List<string> mydata;
var page2 = new Page2(mydata);
Navigation.PushModalAsync(page2);
```

in Page2

```
List<string> Data { get; set; }

public Page2(List<string> data) {
  this.Data = data;
}

public override void OnAppearing() {
  MyListView.ItemsSource = Data;
}
```